# Javascript Regexp replace multiple strings matching property names of another object literal

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have these declared:

```
var obj = {aaa: "came", bbb: "saw", ccc: "conquered", zzz: "discarded" };

var str = "I {aaa}, I {bbb}, I {ccc}. Then I {aaa} again."
```

What I want to do is `str.replace()` each curly braced string with the appropriately named property from `obj`. So in the end, I should have:

```
I came, I saw, I conquered. Then I came again.
```

Thank you.

EDIT:
The linked duplicate indeed proved very appropriate for my case. In addition, answers on that question actually provide dynamic solutions for the case where I did not know the properties of `obj` ahead of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace string {} value to obj (key value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650461/how-to-replace-string-value-to-obj-key-value)

Comment: Downvoter, in case it's due to the duplicate flag, please forgive ;) I actually searched SO a whole lot before going ahead to post a new question. Perhaps that answer didn't come up high on the list because the title has no "RegExp" and no "Javascript"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture what comes between `{}`s, and use a callback for the replacer to look up that captured property on the object:

```js
var obj = {aaa: "came", bbb: "saw", ccc: "conquered", zzz: "discarded" };
var str = "I {aaa}, I {bbb}, I {ccc}. Then I {aaa} again.";

const output = str.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g, (_, prop) => obj[prop]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hey, could you explain how the regex captures everything between `{}`?  How does `[^}]+` capture all characters? What is specifically the point of `^}` ? Thanks

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the link. Though I'm still confused how `[^}]` represents "Match a single character not present in the list below". Why is it *not* ?

Comment: @kemicofa It matches "one or more characters which are not `}`". So the whole pattern means "match `{`, repeatedly match anything but `}`, then match `}`". You could also use `{(.*?)}`, but that's less efficient

Comment: @kemicofa `[...]` match any character in the list, `[^...]` match anything that is not (`^`) in the list

Comment: @Andreas ahh ok. I was thinking of `^` as in first element. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use callback function of replace method

```js
var obj = {aaa: "came", bbb: "saw", ccc: "conquered", zzz: "discarded" };
var str = "I {aaa}, I {bbb}, I {ccc}. Then I {aaa} again."

let op = str.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/g, (_,g1)=> obj[g1] || _)

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Great and elegant! Absolutely new syntax to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and elegant approach is to use [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var obj = {aaa: "came", bbb: "saw", ccc: "conquered", zzz: "discarded" };

var str = `I ${obj.aaa}, I ${obj.bbb}, I ${obj.ccc}. Then I ${obj.aaa} again.`

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. However, this solution would require knowing each and every object property name ahead of time.